# What is the highest value a condition could reach?

Tags: conditions, pathfinder-2e

I'm making a Pathfinder 2e character sheet on Google sheet to automate as much number-crunching as possible. Currently, I'm making a dropdown list for conditions, as well as formulas for calculating their penalties.

I find adding conditions with pre-determined values much simpler than conditions with fillable values. For example, instead of **clumsy** and a blank slot for its value, the dropdown list will have **clumsy 1**, **clumsy 2**, **clumsy 3**, and so on. It's ugly, but it greatly simplifies the formula. However, if a condition's value could reach a really high number, then it will be too cumbersome to use.

The highest I have found is **stupefied 4** from *feeblemind* and *unfathomable song*. I'm also pretty sure I've seen an ancestry/heritage/feat which could increase the maximum value of **dying** to 5.

So what is the highest value/penalty a condition could reach? For the supremely meticulous: what is the highest value each condition could reach?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: If you are looking for a Google sheet character sheet, take a look at the Pathfinder 2e Autosheet: (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mlO-_Bl2wmmJgGwxck3_AxKgCPOc_oxZsHaOqV8B-9Q/edit#gid=1975737288). It has a few minor errors, but is really, really good, and what I use for my games.

Comment: @ESCE Thanks for the character sheet recommendation, it looks awesome! I find making my own character sheet helpful in learning the system though, so I'll keep working on my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Technically limitless

[Vampires](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=97) Drink Blood ability increases the drained condition of a target that has already had their blood drained, with no limit.

> Drinking Blood from a creature that's already drained doesn't restore any HP to the vampire but increases the victim's drain value by 1.

There is no limit mentioned in this ability text.

Additionally, the [Unstoppable Juggernaut Barbarian feat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1631) could technically allow the Wounded condition to infinitely increase:

> In addition, if you are reduced to 0 Hit Points while raging, you can end your rage as a reaction to stay at 1 Hit Point. If you do, you become wounded 2 (or increase your wounded condition by 2 if you are already wounded).

Although there probably isn't much point tracking it past your dying threshold (4 for most characters, 5 with [Diehard](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=774)). For most everything in the game, though, 4 should be a sufficient maximum; it is rare for abilities to go beyond this threshold.

Comment: Thanks to @RevenantBacon for guidance on what turned out to be better search terms. (For reference, I search 'increase condition' on Archive of Nethys).